# Remove new line after pattern and newline between 2 pattern

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have to parse and filter in linux command line only some log files.
after applying some awk and sed commands

```
awk -v RS='+++ ' '!/Diameter|REPT OM BLOCKED|REPT OM STARTING/ { print f $0 } {f=RT}' ./snmplog* | grep -v '+++' | grep -v '++-' | sed -e 's/^\s*//g' | sed -e '/^$/d'
```

I got an output like this which look like an xml file:

```
<Alarm>
<AlarmIndex>8865</AlarmIndex>
<ObjectName>0-0-1#RcvTCAPabortRatio^0-0-3</ObjectName>
<SpecificProblem>KPI OUTSIDE OF CRITICAL THRESHOLD</SpecificProblem>
<ProbableCause>ThresholdCrossed</ProbableCause>
<NotificationIdentifier>8865</NotificationIdentifier>
<Severity>Cleared</Severity>
<AlarmType>QualityOfServiceAlarm</AlarmType>
<AdditionalText></AdditionalText>
<OMText>REPT MEAS KPI
(RcvTCAPabortRatio^0-0-3 = 20) OUTSIDE OF CRITICAL ALARM THRESHOLD (10)</O
MText>
<AlarmCode>922044</AlarmCode>
<AlarmSource>PLATFORM</AlarmSource>
<AlarmTime>Wed Mar 11 00:15:10 2015</AlarmTime>
<RepeatCount>0</RepeatCount>
<OMDBKey>/MS044</OMDBKey>
<AutoClear>1</AutoClear>
</Alarm>

<Alarm>
<AlarmIndex>8928</AlarmIndex>
<ObjectName>0-0-1#RcvTCAPabortRatio^0-0-11</ObjectName>
<SpecificProblem>KPI OUTSIDE OF CRITICAL THRESHOLD</SpecificProblem>
<ProbableCause>ThresholdCrossed</ProbableCause>
<NotificationIdentifier>8928</NotificationIdentifier>
<Severity>Cleared</Severity>
<AlarmType>QualityOfServiceAlarm</AlarmType>
<AdditionalText></AdditionalText>
<OMText>REPT MEAS KPI
(RcvTCAPabortRatio^0-0-11 = 19) OUTSIDE OF CRITICAL ALARM THRESHOLD (10)</
OMText>
<AlarmCode>922044</AlarmCode>
<AlarmSource>PLATFORM</AlarmSource>
<AlarmTime>Wed Mar 11 00:15:10 2015</AlarmTime>
<RepeatCount>0</RepeatCount>
<OMDBKey>/MS044</OMDBKey>
<AutoClear>1</AutoClear>
</Alarm>

<Alarm>
<AlarmIndex>8771</AlarmIndex>
<ObjectName>0-0-1#SuccStandaloneISDRatio</ObjectName>
<SpecificProblem>ZERO DENOMINATOR</SpecificProblem>
<ProbableCause>CorruptData</ProbableCause>
<NotificationIdentifier>8771</NotificationIdentifier>
<Severity>Cleared</Severity>
<AlarmType>ProcessingErrorAlarm</AlarmType>
<AdditionalText></AdditionalText>
<OMText>REPT MEAS KPI
CALCULATION OF (SuccStandaloneISDRatio) FAILED FOR ZERO DENOMINATOR</OMText>
<AlarmCode>922041</AlarmCode>
<AlarmSource>PLATFORM</AlarmSource>
<AlarmTime>Wed Mar 11 01:00:10 2015</AlarmTime>
<RepeatCount>0</RepeatCount>
<OMDBKey>/MS041</OMDBKey>
<AutoClear>1</AutoClear>
</Alarm>
```

I would like to have after threatment something like this:

```
<Alarm><AlarmIndex>8771</AlarmIndex>...<OMText>REPT MEAS KPI
CALCULATION OF (SuccStandaloneISDRatio) FAILED FOR ZERO DENOMINATOR</OMText><AlarmCode>922041</AlarmCode>...</Alarm>
```

I have to remove  all new line after `>` and keep new line between tags.
As you can see in my log I have an issue in the tag `</OMText>` in which I can have a new line also and it should be removed.

I already try with many sed regex found here, but without success

How can I do this?

[Edit]

As requested, please find below the original log file:

```
   +++ FE01 2015-03-11 00:25:35 SNMP /SNM001 #310852 0-0-1 >
   <Alarm>                           
    <AlarmIndex>1119</AlarmIndex>                     
    <ObjectName>0-0-3#destMMENotAvail</ObjectName>    
    <SpecificProblem>CLR error,Diameter Peer:p3.mmeccd.3gppnetwork.org</SpecificProblem>               
    <ProbableCause>CommunicationsSubsystemFailure</ProbableCause>
    <NotificationIdentifier>1119</NotificationIdentifier>
    <Severity>Minor</Severity>                        
    <AlarmType>CommunicationAlarm</AlarmType>         
    <AdditionalText>The destination MME is not reachable</AdditionalText>
    <OMText>CLR error,Diameter Peer:p3.mmeccd.3gppne
   twork.org</OMText>                           
    <AlarmCode>50906</AlarmCode>                      
    <AlarmSource>SDM#RTLTE</AlarmSource>              
    <AlarmTime>Wed Mar 11 00:25:35 2015</AlarmTime>   
    <RepeatCount>0</RepeatCount>                      
    <OMDBKey></OMDBKey>                           
    <AutoClear>1</AutoClear>                          
   </Alarm>                           

   END OF REPORT #310852++-                           

   +++ FE01 2015-03-11 00:25:58 SNMP /SNM001 #310853 0-0-1 >
   <Alarm>                           
    <AlarmIndex>8914</AlarmIndex>                     
    <ObjectName>0-0-14#2AILogger.C!81</ObjectName>    
    <SpecificProblem>OM BLOCKED AILogger.C</SpecificProblem>
    <ProbableCause>QueueSizeExceeded</ProbableCause>  
    <NotificationIdentifier>8914</NotificationIdentifier>
    <Severity>Minor</Severity>                        
    <AlarmType>QualityOfServiceAlarm</AlarmType>      
    <AdditionalText></AdditionalText>                 
    <OMText>REPT OM BLOCKED FOR PROCESS PDLSU1        
      612 MESSAGES DISCARD                           
      OM IDENTITY :                            

      CRERROR BEING BLOCKED; FILE : AILogger.C LINE NUMBER : 81
      </OMText>                           
    <AlarmCode>906065</AlarmCode>                     
    <AlarmSource>PLATFORM</AlarmSource>               
    <AlarmTime>Wed Mar 11 00:25:58 2015</AlarmTime>   
    <RepeatCount>0</RepeatCount>                      
    <OMDBKey>/CR065</OMDBKey>                         
    <AutoClear>1</AutoClear>                          
   </Alarm>                           

   END OF REPORT #310853++-
```

First I have to discared messages which contains within tags: "Diameter", "REPT OM BLOCKED" "REPT OM STARTING" then keeping only the message between the tags ...

Comment: You never need grep or sed when you are using awk so post your ORIGINAL input file, not the file after processing with that bunch of awk/sed/grep-piped commands as you just need 1 command not 20 taped together with pipes.

Comment: The original log file looks this :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '
  /<Alarm>/,/<\/Alarm>/ {
    sub(/^[[:blank:]]+/, "")     # trim leading blanks
    sub(/[[:blank:]]+$/, "")     # trim trailing blanks
    if (/>$/)                    # if the line ends with a tag
      printf "%s", $0            # print it with no newline
    else
      print
  }
  /<\/Alarm>/ {print ""}         # add a newline after each Alarm block
' log.file
```

outputs

```
<Alarm><AlarmIndex>1119</AlarmIndex><ObjectName>0-0-3#destMMENotAvail</ObjectName><SpecificProblem>CLR error,Diameter Peer:p3.mmeccd.3gppnetwork.org</SpecificProblem><ProbableCause>CommunicationsSubsystemFailure</ProbableCause><NotificationIdentifier>1119</NotificationIdentifier><Severity>Minor</Severity><AlarmType>CommunicationAlarm</AlarmType><AdditionalText>The destination MME is not reachable</AdditionalText><OMText>CLR error,Diameter Peer:p3.mmeccd.3gppne
twork.org</OMText><AlarmCode>50906</AlarmCode><AlarmSource>SDM#RTLTE</AlarmSource><AlarmTime>Wed Mar 11 00:25:35 2015</AlarmTime><RepeatCount>0</RepeatCount><OMDBKey></OMDBKey><AutoClear>1</AutoClear></Alarm>
<Alarm><AlarmIndex>8914</AlarmIndex><ObjectName>0-0-14#2AILogger.C!81</ObjectName><SpecificProblem>OM BLOCKED AILogger.C</SpecificProblem><ProbableCause>QueueSizeExceeded</ProbableCause><NotificationIdentifier>8914</NotificationIdentifier><Severity>Minor</Severity><AlarmType>QualityOfServiceAlarm</AlarmType><AdditionalText></AdditionalText><OMText>REPT OM BLOCKED FOR PROCESS PDLSU1
612 MESSAGES DISCARD
OM IDENTITY :

CRERROR BEING BLOCKED; FILE : AILogger.C LINE NUMBER : 81
</OMText><AlarmCode>906065</AlarmCode><AlarmSource>PLATFORM</AlarmSource><AlarmTime>Wed Mar 11 00:25:58 2015</AlarmTime><RepeatCount>0</RepeatCount><OMDBKey>/CR065</OMDBKey><AutoClear>1</AutoClear></Alarm>
```

Answer (score 0):

To pipe (should be modified from original file like you post later)

```
sed '
# don t care out of section
/<Alarm>/,\#</Alarm># !d
# in section
/<Alarm>/,\#</Alarm># {
#  keep line in hold buffer
   H
#  if not the end, loop (cycle to next line and start of script)
   \#</Alarm># !b
#  clean current buffer
   s/.*//
#  exchange buffer (current/hold)
   x
#  remove first new line (extra due to first keep)
   s/\n//

#  remove first new line
   s/\n//
#  reformat first part until OMText
   s#\(</AlarmIndex>\).*\(<OMText>\)#\1...\2#
#  reformat between AlarmCode and /Alarm
   s#\(</AlarmCode>\).*\(</Alarm>\)#\1...\2#
# print result at output
   }' YourFile
```

Self explain, posix version